# Should blending be set on/off in every render call?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, libgdx

This function is required to blend the colors of sprites and to manipulate alphas

```
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
```

Now to get max performance, should I enable and disable `GL_BLEND` every `render()` call or just enable once in the `show()` for the rest of the game object's life ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL uses the state machine concept. Most values stays the same until you modify them. When you enable or disable a feature it is enough to do this once in the initialization phase. Optimising here for performance may be considered premature optimisation. When in doubt always measure.

Comment: My question states two choices and wants one answer/method, the one which will give me better performance!

Comment: "is enough" implies that setting it each frame gives you an unnecessary overhead.